# Second y-axis inside groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I would like to add a second y-axis inside a groupplot. If there's a better/easier way to get the plot I want (see figure) I am willing to not use groupplot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every  tick/.style={black,},width=10cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
        group name=plots,
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt,
        }, xlabel=x,xmin=0, xmax=100,xtick align=outside,xtick pos=left
        ]

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=1000, ylabel= y1,height=6cm, ytick align=outside,ytick pos=left]

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=10, ylabel= y3, ytick={2,4,6,8},height=4cm,ytick align=outside,ytick pos=left]  

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pgfplots` manual has an example showing how to have two ordinates with a normal `axis`, and basically the same technique can be used with `groupplots`.

Some key points:

- Add two `groupplots` environments in the same `tikzpicture`.
- Set the same `xmin` and `xmax` for all axes.
- Add `scale only axis` so that scaling options apply just to the axes, and not labels etc.
- In your code you have `ytick pos=left`, change this to `right` for the second `groupplots`, where the ordinate is on the right side.
- Use `axis y line=left` or `axis y line=right` to print the y axis line only on one side.
- Similarly, `axis x line=none` for the second `groupplots` turns off printing of the x axis line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every  tick/.style={black,},width=10cm}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=0pt,
        },
        xlabel=$x$,
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        xtick align=outside,xtick pos=left,
        scale only axis,
        ytick align=outside,
        ytick pos=left,
        axis y line=left
        ]

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=1000, ylabel=$y_1$,height=6cm, ytick align=outside,ytick pos=left,axis y line=left]

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0, ymax=10, ylabel=$y_3$, ytick={2,4,6,8},height=4cm,]  

\end{groupplot}

\begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
             group name=plots,
             group size=1 by 2,
             xlabels at=edge bottom,
             xticklabels at=edge bottom,
             vertical sep=0pt,
        },
        xmin=0, xmax=100,
        scale only axis,
        ytick align=outside,
        ytick pos=right,
        axis y line=right,
        axis x line=none
        ]

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0,ymax=500,
               ylabel=$y_2$,
               height=6cm,
]

\nextgroupplot[ymin=0,ymax=100,
               ylabel= $y_4$,
               height=4cm,
               ytick={20,40,60,80}]  

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```