# groupplot with two y axes (one at each side of the plot)

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I'm trying to do a graph using groupplots where the reader could read the curves considering the left y axis (frequency), or the right one (time), but the right y axis is not obeying its `ymin` and `ymax` values, and I don't know why. What's wrong here?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm,
    ylabels at=edge left,
},
width=6.7cm, %7.3cm
height=6.7cm, %7.3cm
scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=100e-9,
ymin=3e6,ymax=13e6,
scaled x ticks=false,
change x base,
x SI prefix=nano,
change y base,
ylabel={Frequency},
y SI prefix={mega},
y unit=Hz,
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
]
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={Time},
x unit=s,
only marks,
]
\addplot[blue,mark=square] coordinates {(3.33e-9,3.20e6) (5.e-8,6.03e6) (9.67e-8,3.18e6)};
\addplot[red,mark=triangle] coordinates {(3.33e-9,3.17e6) (5.e-8,6.03e6) (9.67e-8,3.19e6)};
\addplot[black,mark=o] coordinates {(3.33e-9,6.37e6) (5.e-8,1.21e7) (9.67e-8,6.37e6)};
\nextgroupplot[
axis y line=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
grid=none,
xlabel={Frequency},
x SI prefix=giga,
x unit=Hz,
xmin=0.5e9,
xmax=3.5e9,
xtick={0.5e9,1.1e9,1.7e9,2.3e9,2.9e9,3.5e9},
height=0.2cm,
]
\end{groupplot}

\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
},
width=6.7cm, %7.3cm
height=6.7cm, %7.3cm
scale only axis,
]
\nextgroupplot[
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
grid=none,
ylabel={Time},
y SI prefix={nano},
y unit=s,
ymin=1e-10,ymax=4.3333e-10,
]
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm using [Second y-axis inside groupplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251190/second-y-axis-inside-groupplot) as reference, and the above code uses fake data, just to generate a minimal working example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the x-limits as well, e.g. `xmin=0,xmax=1`, and it does work. By default, an `axis` without any data covers the range 0 to 1 for both x and y. Whether intended, an oversight, or a bug, I don't know, but the range of both axes has to be specified, if something other than the default is to be used.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    horizontal sep=1.5cm,
    ylabels at=edge left,
},
width=6.7cm, %7.3cm
height=6.7cm, %7.3cm
scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=100e-9,
ymin=3e6,ymax=13e6,
scaled x ticks=false,
change x base,
x SI prefix=nano,
change y base,
ylabel={Frequency},
y SI prefix={mega},
y unit=Hz,
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
]
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={Time},
x unit=s,
only marks,
]
\addplot[blue,mark=square] coordinates {(3.33e-9,3.20e6) (5.e-8,6.03e6) (9.67e-8,3.18e6)};
\addplot[red,mark=triangle] coordinates {(3.33e-9,3.17e6) (5.e-8,6.03e6) (9.67e-8,3.19e6)};
\addplot[black,mark=o] coordinates {(3.33e-9,6.37e6) (5.e-8,1.21e7) (9.67e-8,6.37e6)};
\nextgroupplot[
axis y line=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
grid=none,
xlabel={Frequency},
x SI prefix=giga,
x unit=Hz,
xmin=0.5e9,
xmax=3.5e9,
xtick={0.5e9,1.1e9,1.7e9,2.3e9,2.9e9,3.5e9},
height=0.2cm,
]
\end{groupplot}

\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
},
width=6.7cm, %7.3cm
height=6.7cm, %7.3cm
scale only axis,
]
\nextgroupplot[
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
grid=none,
ylabel={Time},
y SI prefix={nano},
y unit=s,
ymin=1e-10,ymax=4.3333e-10,
xmin=0,xmax=1 % <------------- added
]
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```